# Why does static images Stretches in React-Native Release Environment

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have created a React-native app. The static images are showing properly in Debug mode but in Release(after creating main.jsbundle and adding it into project) the images Stretches.

I have gone through lots of suggestions on Github but could not find a solution. Some people suggested to use "svgs" instead of "pngs"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did u use resizeMode in image component?

```
<Image source={{ uri: '' }} style={{ }} resizeMode={'contain'} />
```

Comment: tried it but did not work. Moreover, if this was the case then it might not have been working even in Debug Mode

Answer (score 0):

So after all the work and following multiple solutions offered on internet I realised that moving to SVGs is the only possible solution and it worked